# PHP header not prompting download

Tags: php, header, download

I'm stuck...
For some reason no matter what I try, I can't get the browser to prompt me to download a file. I've taken the code below down to the minimum to try and troubleshoot it. What am I missing? When I run this, no prompt is given. When I view the page, it looks like it read the file, its just a bunch of unreadable characters.

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='downloaded.pdf'");
readfile("docs/contract.pdf");
?>
```

Comment: Try in an another window. If you had different header for the same file in same browser window before it can sometimes continue to treat the new content as such. Try a new window

Comment: I tried a new window and new browser with the same results.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the original filename in Content Disposition header.You could try code like this:

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/pdf");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: Binary");  
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=contract.pdf");
readfile("docs/contract.pdf");
?>
```

Also, `Ensure no output before sending headers.` `Sending/modifying HTTP headers must be invoked before any output is made. Otherwise the call fails.`

Comment: I tried the code just as you typed it with the same result. Is there a chance something might be going on at the php config level that would prevent this?

Comment: have u Turnon ur php errors to check if there is any ?

Comment: wow... so I had one line of white space at the top of my page. Apparently this prevents the headers from sending >.<

Comment: Cool. Right, Headers should be first thing before you sending any output to browsers. Othrwse it shows "Headers already sent error..". Thats why i said to turnon php errors. newys..Nice :)

Comment: @Milksnake12 Updated my answer so that other users can get benefit of it. :)